# NoMethodError in Stages#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have two scaffold in rails. first one is project and second one is stage. project has one to many association with stage. i am rendering project and their stages in project#show. but i am unable to add stage edit and destroy button when i add i get method error.
[image: error]

project show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_stage_path(@project, stage) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', stage, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

stages_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @stage = Stage.find(params[:stage_id]
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def show
  @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: :sub_tasks}}).find(params[:id])
  @stages = @project.stages
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks do
        resources :sub_tasks
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where does the local variable `stage` come from?

Comment: @MarkMerritt from projects_controller#show action. i am able to add new stage from project#show page.

Comment: @MarkMerritt what i need to change in stages_controller.rb#edit action in order to edit current stage?

Comment: @Anuj please make sure your route is correct and can you please share your project show code a little more. I want to see where your stage variable was created. View code is needed to solve this issue.